Applications won't open if some time after booting the system passes
Ubuntu 22.04
All apps launch normally right after booting my PC but after 30 minutes or so passes every way of starting anything just stops working. Favorites bar, global search and alt+f2 won't work (terminal, settings, synaptic, trash folder - just to name a few), right click on files like appimages won't work either, right click on deb files won't launch gdebi and so on. Audio/video/images/text files work fine.
When using favorites bar I get a small wheel indicating that app is trying to launch, then it disappears and nothing happens. Other ways cause no reaction, not even a wheel.
If I didn't open nautilus right after booting the PC, all files from the desktop seem to disappear (sure, they are still there but desktop appears empty).
In the meantime, every app launched right after booting my PC works fine (but if I close anything I won't be able to open it back, of course).
As a result I'm either forced to always immediately launch everything I might require during the day or reboot the system any time new programme is needed.
What should I check and what additional info should I provide?
